# Having some problems accessing items in an array

Tags: php, arrays

I received an array from another server, but i want to fetch the emails only.

The code:

```
var_dump($search_result["response"]);
```

It shows something like:
http://pastebin.com/LbLaQYy4

When I use:

```
var_dump($search_result["response"]["results"][0]["collection"]["payer"]["email"]);
```

I shows just one email.

How to fetch all emails ?

Comment: You have a stackoverflow for the portuguese community [pt.stackoverflow.com](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/)

Comment: Based on the little information your have posted here, I would say you need to loop over `$search_result["response"]["results"]`.

Comment: You can show me how to do it?

Comment: @Hocrux See the answer that has been posted.

Comment: @Praveen Kumar So what he has now delete the last line of the question but he explained he was struggling with explaining his problem in english. So I said if it would be easier he could try the portuguese version.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You'll need to loop through the returned array in order to fetch all the email addresses.

```
$emails = array();
foreach($search_result["response"]["results"] as $result) {
    $emails []= $result["collection"]["payer"]["email"];
}
var_dump($emails);
```

`$emails` should contain the data you're after.